# question in ckecing Fringe and Expanded list in A-Star alogrithm Python

Tags: python, list, tree, artificial-intelligence

How would you delete an element in a fringe that is similar to the expanded list? In A-Star once you expanded a node you cannot revisit that node in the fringe.

Because simple test cases such as [0, 1, 2, 3, 8, 4, 6, 7, 5] work fine but when it comes to more complex cases such as [6, 4, 0, 1, 5, 3, 7, 8, 2] the program runs and it seems like there are repeated items being expanded.

Here is my code:

```
from math import sqrt
import time
#fring- to keep the nodes 
#expand: the function to expand one node at a time 
    #heuristic: calculate the cheapest cost
    #f()- total cost 
    #h()- the number index to the goal 
#expanded_nodes- have all the visited 
startime = time.time_ns()
def astar(puzzle):
    #intializing the variables 
    cost = 0
    node = Node(puzzle,cost)
    loop = True
 
    #the possible nodes  
    fringe = []  
    #After expanding the list 
    expanded = []

    # maybe need it keep it for now 
    visit = set() #keep track of all the visit 
    
    #the goal state
    goal = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8] 
    
    #possible combination move
    possible_move = [[1,3],[0,2,4],[1,5],[0,4,6],[1,3,5,7],[2,4,8],[3,7],[4,6,8],[5,7]]
   
    #intialization of the first node 
    fringe = [node]
    #print('state:'+str(node.state))
    
    #start the loop 
    while loop:
        print('\nthe state of this game position is:\n ' + str(node.state) +"\n\n")
        #find the lowest cost in the fringe then expand the lowest cost node
        min_cost = fringe[0].cost 
        min_node = fringe[0]
        for node in fringe:
            if node.cost < min_cost:
                min_cost = node.cost
                min_node = node
        #append the node that was just expaneded into the expanded list but keep the list not expaneded in fringe 
        expanded.append(min_node)
        print('the min node '+str(min_node.state)+'\nthe cheapest cost: '+ str(min_cost) + '\n')
       
        #removes the min cost node from fringe  
        for node in fringe[:]:
            if node.state == min_node.state:
                fringe.remove(node)
               
        #when there is a solution in the expanded 
        for node in expanded:
            if node.state == goal:
                loop = False
                
        #checking the node in fringe 
        for node in fringe:
            print(node.state)
            
            
        #     key = tuple(node.state)
        # if key in visit:
        #     continue
        # visit.add(key)
        #traverse the nodes that was expanded and add the children to the fringe 
       # for node in expanded[:]:
        for node in expanded[:]:
            #append all the successor/children and set the children's parent to fringe 
            blank = node.state.index(8)
            print('the index of the blank is '+ str(blank))
            print('\n')
            possible_pos = possible_move[blank]
            print('possible pos '+ str(possible_pos))
                
            for i in possible_pos:
                #if node not in visit:
                    print('\n')
                    possible_sw = node.state[:]
                    print('index swap = '+ str(i))
                    possible_sw[blank] = possible_sw[i]
                    possible_sw[i] = 8
                    print('the child node is ' + str(possible_sw))
                    node.cost = manhattan(possible_sw, goal)
                    fringe.append(Node(possible_sw,node.cost,node))
                    print('the cost this node state: '+ str(node.cost)) 
   
        for node in expanded[:]:
            if node.cost > min_cost:
                expanded.pop(0)

    #finding the solution 
    solution = expanded
    move = 0
    while node.parent:
        solution.append(node.state.index(8))
        node = node.parent
        move += 1
    print('moves made '+ str(move))

    solution.reverse()
    print('moves list '+ str(solution))
    endtime = time.time_ns()
    executionTime = ( endtime - startime)
    print('Execution time in ns: ' + str(executionTime))
    
    
    return solution     

#Try the Manhattan Distance for moving only four direction up,down,left,right 
def manhattan(a, b):
        return sum(abs(val1-val2) for val1, val2 in zip(a,b))

class Node:
    def __init__(self,state,cost,parent = None):
        self.parent = parent
        self.state = state
        self.cost = cost
        self.children = []


#test case 
p = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 7]
p = [0, 1, 2, 3, 8, 4, 6, 7, 5]
#p= [6, 4, 0, 1, 5, 3, 7, 8, 2]
#p = [1, 8, 2, 0, 3, 5, 6, 4, 7]

#p =  [1, 3, 2, 0, 5, 7, 6, 8, 4]
print("++++++++++A*++++++++++++")
astar(p)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Wed Feb  8 20:24:42 2023

@author: Jenna Schulte
"""

from math import sqrt
import time

startime = time.time_ns()

def astar(puzzle):

    cost = 0
    node = Node(puzzle,cost)
    loop = True
    fringe = []
    expanded = []
    visit = set()

    goal = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
    possible_move = [[1,3],[0,2,4],[1,5],[0,4,6],[1,3,5,7],[2,4,8],[3,7],[4,6,8],[5,7]]

    fringe = [node]

    while loop:

        print('\nthe state of this game position is:\n ' + str(node.state) +"\n\n")

        min_cost = fringe[0].cost
        min_node = fringe[0]
        for node in fringe:
            if node.cost < min_cost:
                min_cost = node.cost
                min_node = node

        expanded.append(min_node)
        print('the min node '+str(min_node.state)+'\nthe cheapest cost: '+ str(min_cost) + '\n')

        for node in fringe[:]:
            if node.state == min_node.state:
                fringe.remove(node)

        for node in expanded:
            if node.state == goal:
                loop = False

        for node in expanded[:]:
            blank = node.state.index(8)
            possible_pos = possible_move[blank]

            for i in possible_pos:
                possible_sw = node.state[:]
                possible_sw[blank] = possible_sw[i]
                possible_sw[i] = 8
                node.cost = manhattan(possible_sw, goal)
                child_node = Node(possible_sw,node.cost,node)
                key = tuple(child_node.state)
                if key not in visit:
                    visit.add(key)
                    fringe.append(child_node)

    
        expanded.pop(0)

    solution = expanded
    move = 0
    while node.parent:
        solution.append(node.state.index(8))
        node = node.parent
        move += 1

    print('moves made '+ str(move))
    solution.reverse()
    print('moves list '+ str(solution))

    endtime = time.time_ns()
    executionTime = ( endtime - startime)
    print('Execution time in ns: ' + str(executionTime))

    return solution

def manhattan(a, b):
        return sum(abs(val1-val2) for val1, val2 in zip(a,b))
class Node:
    def __init__(self,state,cost,parent = None):
        self.parent = parent
        self.state = state
        self.cost = cost
        self.children = []
        
p = [0, 1, 2, 3, 8, 4, 6, 7, 5]
p =[0, 4, 1, 3, 8, 2, 6, 7, 5]
p= [6, 4, 0, 1, 5, 3, 7, 8, 2]
astar(p)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).